# HPQC: Copy test cases to a new project along with the test sets they have been executed in

Tags: manual-testing, quality-center, testcase

I have a test case folder I am looking to copy into a different project. All the test cases have been executed and are in different test sets. When I copy over the test case folder, I would like to copy over the test sets they have been executed in as well. Can this be done. Please help.

thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Need you to tell us more details

Comment: You can copy all that data if you create a new project, if the project is already created it may be possible to create an OTA script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By using Test plan module you can copy your test cases to another project.If you try on Test lab module it wont work. make sure you are in the Test Plan module when trying to copy the folder.

But you cannot copy the status, because it will be a new project you need to run them again.